# Update mysql database with sql subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I need to write a patch for my `adNote` table in which I store information for notes placed on top of images. A row is assigned a `noteParentId` whenever a revision is uploaded and notes are copied over onto it.

**My Main Goal:**

For each group of rows with `noteParentId` the same, I want to set the row with the highest `revision` to have a value of `1` for the `isLatest` field. As you can see in my example "After the Patch", I want to set rows 203, 204 and 205 with a value of `1` for `isLatest` since they are the latest versions of those notes.

**Before Patch**

```
╔══════════╦══════════════╗═════════════╗═════════════╗
║    id    ║ noteParentId ║   revision  ║   isLatest  ║
╠══════════╬══════════════╣═════════════╣═════════════╣
║    200   ║      200     ║       0     ║       0     ║
║    201   ║      200     ║       1     ║       0     ║
║    202   ║      200     ║       2     ║       0     ║
║    203   ║      200     ║       3     ║       0     ║
║    204   ║      204     ║       0     ║       0     ║
║    205   ║      205     ║       0     ║       0     ║
╚══════════╩══════════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╝
```

**After Patch**

```
╔══════════╦══════════════╗═════════════╗═════════════╗
║    ID    ║ noteParentId ║   revision  ║   isLatest  ║
╠══════════╬══════════════╣═════════════╣═════════════╣
║    200   ║      200     ║       0     ║       0     ║
║    201   ║      200     ║       1     ║       0     ║
║    202   ║      200     ║       2     ║       0     ║
║    203   ║      200     ║       3     ║       1     ║
║    204   ║      204     ║       0     ║       1     ║
║    205   ║      205     ║       0     ║       1     ║
╚══════════╩══════════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╝
```

I was thinking I could run a query like the one below, but I am receiving a mysql error

**Query attempt:**

```
UPDATE adNote AS a1
SET a1.isLatest = 1
WHERE a1.id IN (
SELECT a2.id
FROM adNote AS a2
WHERE MAX(a2.revision)
GROUP BY a2.noteParentId
)
```

**MySql Error:**

```
Error : Invalid use of group function
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Given the error, I presume it's `mysql` and not `tsql`.

Comment: It is mysql. I have it within my question and my tags. Is there any other info I can offer?

Comment: Why would you update for 204 and 205 but not for 200?

Comment: @sgeddes thanks for pointing that out. The original version of the note should have a `noteParentId` the same as the `id`. I have changed the table examples to reflect this. So basically we update 203, 204, and 205 because they are the latest versions of the notes with the same `noteParentId`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
update adNote a 
join (select noteParentId, max(revision) maxrevision
      from adNote
      group by noteParentId) a2 on a.noteParentId = a2.noteParentId 
             and a.revision = a2.maxrevision
set a.isLatest = 1;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd6c9/1)

Comment: That did it. Thank you so much for your patience and help.